# How does use apply and mutate for create a new variable?

Tags: r, apply, dplyr

Let´s say I have the following DF

```
df<-data.frame(name=c(rep("AUS",5), rep("FRA",5), rep("SPA",5)),
           Date=rep(seq(as.Date("2020/1/1"), as.Date("2020/1/5"), "days"),3),
           mean= c(19, 2, 22, 13, 23, 24, 7, 14, 27, 30, 4, 26, 1, 18, 5))
```

My idea is create a new variable using the variable `mean`. The first thing is to group the  the DF because the new variable has to be estimated for groups.

```
df<-df%>%group_by(name)
```

I want that my first observation be used with the other rows, I want to say that my new variable will be the result of:

> 19, 19/2, 19/22, 19/13, 19/23, 24, 24/7,..... 4/5

I though that i could use the `apply` command with `group` and `mutate` but I am having problems for finding the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `first` to get first data for each group (`name`) and divide it by `mean` value.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(res = c(first(mean), first(mean)/mean[-1])) %>%
  ungroup

#  name  Date        mean    res
#   <chr> <date>     <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 AUS   2020-01-01    19 19    
# 2 AUS   2020-01-02     2  9.5  
# 3 AUS   2020-01-03    22  0.864
# 4 AUS   2020-01-04    13  1.46 
# 5 AUS   2020-01-05    23  0.826
# 6 FRA   2020-01-01    24 24    
# 7 FRA   2020-01-02     7  3.43 
# 8 FRA   2020-01-03    14  1.71 
# 9 FRA   2020-01-04    27  0.889
#10 FRA   2020-01-05    30  0.8  
#11 SPA   2020-01-01     4  4    
#12 SPA   2020-01-02    26  0.154
#13 SPA   2020-01-03     1  4    
#14 SPA   2020-01-04    18  0.222
#15 SPA   2020-01-05     5  0.8
```

This can be written in base R -

```
transform(df, res = ave(mean, name, FUN = function(x) c(x[1], x[1]/x[-1])))
```

and `data.table` -

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, res := c(first(mean), first(mean)/mean[-1]), name]
```

Comment: This is the same approach that i was using, but I still have a problem. The first observation can not be 1. The first observation of my new variable has to be equal to the first observation of mean (by groups).

Comment: @EveChanatasig Got it...See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution with `ifelse` to specify your two conditions: if the `mean` is the first in the group, then use `mean`; if it is not the first in the group, then divide the first `mean` by the `mean` value:

```
df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(new = ifelse(mean == first(mean), mean, first(mean)/mean))
# A tibble: 15 x 4
# Groups:   name [3]
   name  Date        mean    new
   <chr> <date>     <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 AUS   2020-01-01    19 19    
 2 AUS   2020-01-02     2  9.5  
 3 AUS   2020-01-03    22  0.864
 4 AUS   2020-01-04    13  1.46 
 5 AUS   2020-01-05    23  0.826
 6 FRA   2020-01-01    24 24    
 7 FRA   2020-01-02     7  3.43 
 8 FRA   2020-01-03    14  1.71 
 9 FRA   2020-01-04    27  0.889
10 FRA   2020-01-05    30  0.8  
11 SPA   2020-01-01     4  4    
12 SPA   2020-01-02    26  0.154
13 SPA   2020-01-03     1  4    
14 SPA   2020-01-04    18  0.222
15 SPA   2020-01-05     5  0.8
```